# Bootstrap reorder columns when re-sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

most of my coding problems are usually solved very easily by searching on here (hence this is my first post) but for this one I just can't find an answer.

I've made a simple bootstrap grid using the w3 tutorials.

I have columns A, B, C.  Column A has only 1 element (a google map), columns B and C have 4 rows each (let's call them B1-B4 and C1-C4):

[What I have made (large screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdXVI.png)

When I resize the browser window such that it turns into a mobile size screen it shows just 1 column in the order of A, B1-B4, C1-C4.

[What I get when I re-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQqNZ.png)

What I want is it to re-order the columns to A, B1, C1, B2, C2, ..., B4, C4

[What I want when I re-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfcyv.png)

If anyone has the solution, or can point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a **Minimal Working Example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask] for more info.

Comment: See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reorder columns in pure Bootstrap 3 without using a minimum of Javascript.

One workaround could be to have hidden columns at the cost of containing twice your data using `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md`, `hidden-lg` and `hidden-xs` classes to hide columns according to the device [as explained here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - how would you approach doing this in js?

Comment: I would not, but it's a personnal choice

Comment: Bootstrap Version Beta 2 has this functionality:

Order: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Comment: Noobit that was exactly what I wanted thanks, wish I hadn't followed that tutorial now as I'm trying to update everything to version 4!

Answer (score 0):

[Complete Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can use flexbox ordering to set the order of your children elements however you like. So if you wanted A, B1, C1, B2, C2, you could set A to 1, B1 to 2, C1 to 3 and so on.

However lets say you had like an unknown / infinite number of items for B or C, you could wrap B and C in a flex container, and set the order there, and then inside that, set the order for individual items.

Even better, start using CSS Grid, the successor to flexbox. I don't have too much experience with CSS Grid, but it looks like you can define the order, just like flexbox.

[CSS Grid by Example - Mozilla Developer Network](https://gridbyexample.com/video/series-auto-placement-order/)